# Mongoose connection/models: Need to always run on open?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, express

I am using Mongoose 3 and the most obvious way to connect to database is

```
conn = mongoose.createConnection(...)
conn.on("open", ...)
```

Question is, do I need to define all my models in the open callback? If that is so, I will have to create a `initMongoose.coffee` that looks like

```
# initMongoose.coffee

mongoose = require "mongoose"
module.exports = mongoose.createConnection ...

# modelExample.coffee

conn = require "./initDatabase"
conn.on "open", -> 
    ... define model?
    modeule.exports = model # I think this does not work?
```

I think I read somewhere in Node docs that modules cannot be defined in a callback like that?

---

Since I am only using 1 connection, I think I can use

```
mongoose.connect ...
```

Which doesnt accepts any callbacks so I suppose is synchronous? Can I define all my models and thus queries right after `connect()`? It works at the moment, but it might be because its fast enough.

Comment: Thanks for asking the question. I see all sorts of example not putting it in the callback and I was baffled! Also I was wondering how I would structure the program if I have to put it in the callback.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mongoose buffers up commands until it is finished connecting, so you can treat it like it's synchronous and define your models and start using the library whenever you want; only once you want to start actually inserting or retrieving data do you need to make the connection.

Comment: Erm your 2nd part seems to contradict with the 1st. So, I can define models right after connect but can I do the same with inserts?

Comment: Yes; the point is, while connecting is asynchronous, you don't have to treat it like that, as Mongoose will detect that it isn't finished connecting and buffer the inserts until after it's done.

Comment: @MichelleTilley source?