# How to detect MongoDB is open in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

All:

I am pretty new to Mongoose, right now, I want to organize my code structure like:

One db config file to init connection:

```
//db.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function (callback) {
  // yay!
});
module.exports = mongoose;
```

And another file store model:

```
//model.js
var mongoose = require("./db");
var kittySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
var fluffy = new Kitten({ name: 'fluffy' });
fluffy.save(function (err, fluffy) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  fluffy.speak();
});
```

What confuses me is: **if I structure the code like this, how can I know the connection is ready in model.js**(I know current async pattern can not guarantee connection is open )

Thanks

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910842/mongoose-connection-models-need-to-always-run-on-open

Comment: @qqilihq Thanks, so basically I do not need to worry about this... I will give it a try again

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
   // Do something
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain your answer a bit? Popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to. Thanks!